# JSON property name as whole JSON path to the property

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I want that every JSON property name represents the path to it.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json I currently get this JSON:

```
{
   "firstName":"Homer",
   "lastName":"Simpson",
   "address":{
      "street":"Evergreen Terrace",
      "streetNumber":"742"
   }
}
```

Is it possible to get this JSON instead:

```
{
   "person.firstName":"Homer",
   "person.lastName":"Simpson",
   "person.address":{
      "person.address.street":"Evergreen Terrace",
      "person.address.streetNumber":"742"
   }
}
```

Comment: You would need to postprocess your JSON afterwards.  Json.NET is a contract-based serializer, so if multiple `Address` objects appear in the graph, it's going to serialize them the same way using the same contract.  You want a different contract (because different property names) for each occurrence of `Address` in the graph.  Serializing to `JObject` and fixing the property names afterwards would seem to be the way to go.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, 'cause it's ambiguous. How would this file be deserialized?

In C#, it could be interpreted as...

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Person.firstName { get; set; }
    public string Person.LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Person.Address { get; set; }
}
```

It's a invalid format, so your file must cause a Exception or a compilation error.

Try this on browser, using `JSON.parse()` method and you'll get a object with this structure (the property names with a dot).

Answer (score 0):

this format is invalid . but :
sample

```
        private static string _getCustomJsonFormat(object o, string _parentPath = "")
    {
        string str = "{" ;
        {

            var t = o.GetType();
            var props = t.GetProperties();
            if (props != null)
            {
                List<string> _kv = new List<string>();
                foreach (var i in props)
                {
                    List<string> _path = new List<string>() { };
                    if (_parentPath.Length == 0) _path.Add(t.Name);
                    _path.AddRange(_parentPath.Split('.').Select(m => m.Trim()).Where(m => m.Length > 0));
                    string _p = i.Name; 
                    object _v = i.GetValue(o);
                    Type _vt = _v.GetType();
                    _path.Add(_p);
                    if (_vt.IsNested)
                    {
                        // Get Object
                        _kv.Add("\"" + string.Join(".",_path) + "\":" + _getCustomJsonFormat(_v, string.Join(".", _path)));
                    }
                    else {
                        // Get Property
                        _kv.Add("\"" + string.Join(".", _path)+ "\":\"" + _v.ToString() + "\"");
                    }
                }
                str += string.Join(",", _kv);

            }
        }
        return str+" }";
    }
```

use :

```
            var p = new Person() { Address = new Address() { Street = "1", StreetNumber = "2" }, FirstName = "a", LastName = "b" };
        var x = _getCustomJsonFormat(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET will not serialize an object using JSONPaths as property names out of the box because it is a contract-based serializer.  As such, it will serialize all instances of some type `T` in the same way wherever they are encountered in the serialization graph.  You, conversely, want a slightly different contract for each instance encountered that reflects the path to the instance in the graph.

So, what are your options to get the JSON you require?

**Firstly**, you could serialize to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) then postprocess it using the `public static void Rename(this JToken token, string newName)` extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269811/3744182) by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) to *[Rename JProperty in json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47267542/3744182)*:

```
var person = new Person
{
    // Initialize your Person as required
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};
var jObject = JObject.FromObject(person, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
foreach (var item in jObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Select(p => (Property: p, p.Path)).ToList())
{
    // The Rename extension method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269811/3744182
    item.Property.Rename("person." + item.Path);
}

var json = jObject.ToString();
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gqYetS).

**Secondly**, you could rename the properties on the fly as you serialize by subclassing [`JsonTextWriter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs) and overriding the [`WritePropertyName()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_WritePropertyName.htm) methods:

```
public class NameRemappingJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    readonly Action<string> jsonWriterWritePropertyName;
    readonly Func<string, int, string, string> map;

    public NameRemappingJsonWriter(TextWriter textWriter, Func<string, int, string, string> map) : base(textWriter)
    {
        this.map = map ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(map));
        //Method to call a base-of-base-class method taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32562464
        //By https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk
        //To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method
        var ptr = typeof(JsonWriter).GetMethod("WritePropertyName", new[] { typeof(string) }).MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
        jsonWriterWritePropertyName = (Action<string>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Action<string>), this, ptr);
    }

    public override void WritePropertyName(string name) => WritePropertyName(name, true);

    public override void WritePropertyName(string name, bool escape)
    {
        jsonWriterWritePropertyName(name);
        WriteRaw(JsonConvert.ToString(map(name, Top, Path)));
        WriteRaw(":");
    }       
}
```

And then later:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};
Func<string, int, string, string> map = (name, depth, parentPath) => "person." + parentPath;
using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
using (var jsonWriter = new NameRemappingJsonWriter(textWriter, map) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
{
    JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(jsonWriter, person);
}
var json = textWriter.ToString();
```

Note that, to get this to work, I had to call the base-of-base-class `JsonWriter.WritePropertyName()` methods, which is slightly sketchy and [not recommended or supported natively in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2327821/3744182).

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z54BGC).